# For loop a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, brute-force

I'm trying to write a brute force python script. I'm following this tutorial [link](https://inventwithpython.com/chapter14.html) and modified it to suit my needs. most of the code works fine except the output is only one output instead of 26

```
file = args.imp
MAX_KEY_SIZE = 26
message = open(file)

def getKey():
    key = 0
    print("Enter the key number (1-%s)" % (MAX_KEY_SIZE))
    key = int(input())
    while True:
            if (key >= 1 and key <= MAX_KEY_SIZE):
                    return key

def decode(message, key):
    translated = ''


    for symbol in message.read():

            num = ord(symbol)
            num += key

            if num > ord('Z'):
                    num -= 26
            elif num < ord('A'):
                    num += 26
            translated += chr(num)
    return translated


key = getKey()

for k in range(1, MAX_KEY_SIZE + 1):
    print(k, decode(message, key))
```

output is:

```
Enter the key number (1-26)
4
1 BDPWCCONVESDKLOOVACAXKYFJJBGDCSLRRPTYYYIBQNOXLZYHCHCNZCRM
2
3 
4
5
6 etc to 26
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you call read(), It reads through the entire file and leaves the read cursor positioned at end of the file. When you read file with this situation it will return you `''` (empty string). That is reason, you are getting output at first iteration only and rest as empty.

You can seek (point cursor at beginning of the file) as answered by @schwobaseggl.

OR read all file once at beginning,

```
message = open(file).read()

# code here

def decode(message, key):
    translated = ''
    for symbol in message:
            num = ord(symbol)
            num += key
            if num > ord('Z'):
                    num -= 26
            elif num < ord('A'):
                    num += 26
            translated += chr(num)
    return translated
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot read a file again and again just like that. You must set the file object's position back to the beginning. Otherwise, `message.read()` will just return an empty string. Add

```
message.seek(0)
```

to the beginning of your `decode` function.